# MS Access Datasheet view

Tags: ms-access, multiple-columns, datasheet

I have created a subform in Access that contains a combo box and multiple textboxes.
I can view this form as a datasheet view and see a single line containing all the fields that I wish to have, but cannot add any more lines after this information.

Can anyone tell me how to make this datasheet show multiple lines?

Here is an image of the subform in both design and datasheet view:

Datasheet View
[image: Datasheet View]

Design View
[image: Design View]

Answer (score 1):

Do not use datasheet view if you want to use multiple lines. Use Multiple Items form type. You can manually create any number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

The datasheet view of a form corresponds to a recordset. Assigning a table or a query to the form's recordsource will cause the datasheet view to show one line per record.

The design view is used to modify and customize the form view of the form. For the datasheet one, you can merely add / remove which fields of the underlying recordset you wish to display, and change the controls' bound sources, etc.